# upload images to facebook page albums, got #240 exception

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

i am trying to upload images to page ablbum with facebook graph

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption',
'source' => '@' . realpath(ABSPATH.$image_realpath) 
, 'access_token' => $page_access_token);
$data = $facebook->api('/'. $album_id . '/photos/', 'post', $args);
print_r($data);
```

but it gives me this exeception

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#240) This user isn't allowed to upload photos to this object's wall
```

i am the admin of the  page and i added `manaege_pages`, `publish_stream`, `share_item`, `offline_access` permissions to my app and still having this problem

Comment: Where are you setting the access token?

Comment: i added it but still facing the same problem

Comment: iam using the page access token, is it right or should i use the user access token?

Comment: Did you try with the user access token?

Comment: i tried it now, but also got the same error

Comment: i used graph to create album, it worked correctly but in uploading images not working, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting scope (Permission) in app settings : '**manage_pages**'

try this :

```
$DestinationFile = 'images/filename.jpg';
$newImagePath = "@" . realpath($DestinationFile);
$response = $facebook->api(
            '/me/photos/', 'post', array(
            'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(),
            'message' => 'This is an awesome tech website : http://www.technew.in ' ,
            'source' => $newImagePath
        ));
print_r($response);
```

Comment: solved guys thanks god, i was typing a wrong id for the album